# Query By Humming system

Tags: python

I need to identify the songs by human hum. what are the best methodology and algorithm that i can use for achieve that. I search for code samples. But I couldn't find. Please help me....

Comment: This is too broad as a question here, and probably too difficult if you're doing an undergraduate degree CompSci project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could begin a python program that uses [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) to deep-learn the correspondence between humming and songs -  it should fall under the umbrella initiative by Google Brain called [Magenta](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/).
Of course for [Deep-Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) you would need to have a large corpus of examples to learn from.